# Get an ID if two other ID matches in two different tables

Tags: asp.net-mvc, linq

I have a table for Images, one for Jobs and one for Users. When a user post a job I want to assign an Image of that users automatically from the table Image. I don't want to save User ImageID in Job table, because when a Company wants to update the logo/image it should update automatically all his jobs with his new image only from the table Image and UserID and not updating the row with ImageID from Job table.

Here what I tried:

```
    var listOfJobs = db.Jobs.AsEnumerable();

    var ProfileImage = db.Images.Where(
                     p => listOfJobs.Any(l => p.UserID == l.ApplicationUsers.Id)).ToList();

    return View(ProfileImage);
```

With the code above it shows all the images in Image table in all jobs.

I should try with a Join? I kinda don't know how to use join and I don't if its fit for this situation.

Thank you very much

Comment: You know that your `AsEnumerable` prevents the usage of the database? Your query will load all into memory and filter there. No sql will be generated but `SELECT * FROM db.Jobs`. That might work but is not efficient and may fail in future if the table grows.

Comment: Small correction: Only if lazy loading is turned off. If it's on, then db.Images will generate a hell lot of SQL query

Comment: @Hegi: interesting, didn't know. I thought that `AsEnumerable` would call the Linq-To-Object methods instead. So for every image in `Images` `Enumerable.Any` is called.

Comment: I deleted `AsEnumerable` and I have the same result. All images are shown in all Jobs.

Comment: @Eduard: it's not really clear what you're trying to achieve. `ProfileImage` is singular, so it should contain only one matching image, is that correct? Why are you using `Where...ToList` at all? Use `FirstOrDefault`.

Comment: Your intent is unclear. You are getting all jobs and then getting all images if the ApplicationUser has ever an image.

Comment: I think you need to have a table between Jobs and Images ( `JobImages`) it  stores the current `JobId` and `ImageId`, and you can use it for history also if you added `IsActive` ( bit) and `CreatedOn` (Date)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do the following

1- add new class/table `JobImage` if you don't have one already, assuming that the id type is `int` , this table will store each Job with its corresponding image

```
public class JobImage
{
     public int JobID{get;set;}
     public int ImageID{get;set;}

     public Job {get;set;}
     public Image{get;set;}
}
```

2- now your query will become as follows:

```
var ProfileImage = (from a in db.ApplicationUsers
                   join ij in db.JobImages on a.JobID equals ij.JobID
                   join i in db.Images on ij.ImageID equals i.ImageID
                   where a.UserID == **YourUserID**
                   select i).SingleOrDefault()

    return View(ProfileImage);
```

3- some scenarios you might take into consideration

1. The way I introduced the new class / table, both JobID and ImageID
   are Primary keys and foreign keys
2. You can add a Primary Key `JobImageID` and `JobID` and `ImageID` only foreign keys and you might add `IsActive` as bit and also `CreatedOn` date, to track the history

hope this will help you

Comment: I didn't had really time to try this in last month, but for two days I am trying to get this working and I don't understand why I need a 3rd table 'JobImages'. I tried to Join User table with Image table but it gives all the Images from the Table. Or I tried another approach: `(from a in img
                                   from b in user
                                   where a.UserID == b.Id select a).ToList();`. And `Where` clause is totally ignored and is returning all records not Image.Userid == Users.Id. Why?